# Use of Prometheus scrape_timeout

Tags: configuration, devops, prometheus

In the prometheus configuration I have a job with these specs:

```
- job_name: name_of_my_job
     scrape_interval: 5m
     scrape_timeout: 30s
     metrics_path: /metrics
     scheme: http
```

The script that creates the metrics takes 3 minutes to finish, but from prometheus I don't see the metrics. What is the operation of the scrape_timeout variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every 5 minutes (scrape_interval) Prometheus will get the metrics from the given URL. It will try 30 seconds (scrape_timeout) to get the metrics if it can't **scrape** in this time it will time out.